# Android Fused location api's, provides wrong location update when i am at home and latch to my WiFi network

Tags: android, android-fusedlocation

I have made an application that gets location update after 10 seconds, it is working very fine when i am in office,on road etc. but when i am in home and connected to my WiFi network then, I in the `onLocationChanged(Location location)` method i got location which is 55Km from my home, which is highly inaccurate? Any help to avoid this location update.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022297/fused-location-provider-doesnt-seem-to-use-gps-receiver) post?

Location is not always accurate, especially indoors.

Comment: thanks, but problem is that it is highly inaccurate near about 55 Km. it looks like that, WiFi Mapping with location is wrong.

Comment: Could be an issue with ip - address mapping of your provider.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered that in some cases, too.
Have you moved (apartment) recently? It takes weeks for big brother (AKA Google) to understand that your WiFi position has changed. It learns where each WiFi is and doesn't hasten to update that knowledge.

Worse: I suspect that even if you have a neighbour that moved from far away, you may appear - that far away, too.

The only heuristic I can draw from my belt is to eliminate impossible location changes such as huge distances in low times (unless you have a TARDIS time machine parking downstairs ;-) ). You don't do 2000Km/h just like that. Altitudes may also be a good hint. You can't be in altitude 3000m if you live in London or New York.